# Scaling factor for convolution in matlab to get proper area

Tags: matlab, convolution

The question is pretty basic, I try to repeat results for continues convolution of two boxcar functions with `conv` function in matlab. Accordingly to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution it should result in the area overlap between the two given function. The results of discrete  `conv` should be scaled to get a proper value for the area. Some suggest scaling with sampling frequency, but it does not give correct results for the area. It was suggested to use `sum(f)` in [Scale Factor in Matlabs `conv()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412097/scale-factor-in-matlabs-conv) but it does not work either. Can anybody explain what scaling factor should be used? Or maybe there is an error in the following code?

```
dx = 0.01
xmin = -0.7;
xmax =  0.7;
box = @(x) 0.5 * (sign(x - xmin) - sign(x - xmax));

x  = -2:dx:2;
f1 = box(x); 
f2 = box(x) * 1.5;
conv1 = conv(f1, f2, 'same');           % no scaling
conv2 = conv(f1, f2, 'same') * dx;      % scale with sampling frequency
conv3 = conv(f1 / sum(f1), f2, 'same'); % scale with sum of f1
conv4 = conv(f1, f2 / sum(f2), 'same'); % scale with sum of f2
conv5 = conv(f1 / sum(f1), f2 / sum(f1), 'same'); % scale with sum of f1 and f2
exact = ones(size(x)) * (xmax - xmin) * min(max(f1), max(f2));
plot(x, f1, 'c--o', x, f2, 'm--o' ...    % plot functions for reference 
     , x, conv2, 'r-'        ... 
     , x, conv3, 'g-'        ... 
     , x, conv4, 'b-'        ... 
     , x, conv5, 'y-'        ... 
     , x, exact, 'k:'         ...    % excat area
     );
legend({'f1' 'f2' 'dx scale' 'f1 scale' 'f2 scale' 'f1 and f2 scale' 'exact'})
```

[image: Results produced by the code above]

Comment: As far as my understanding of convolutions go, the red curve looks spot-on. Look at the definition in the Wikipedia article you linked to and substitute 't' with 0. You get a value of 2.1 which is approimately where the figure says the red curve lies

Comment: If you need overlap, something like this would work too: g=[f1;f2]; gmin = min(g,[],1); overlap = trapz(x,gmin); (I assume all functions are positive. If they aren't you need to figure out some algebra.)

Comment: @bas, at t = 0 the position of "boxes" is actually shown in the attache figure, and overlapping area is the area of the small box, that is 1.4. I'd like to understand how `conv` function works, not only find the overlap, but thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: think of convolution as the weighted sum of a function weighted by another function. there may be 'deep' reasons for the time flipping of the second function, but the way i understand it, the time flipping makes some fourier analyses look very pretty. so it stuck